# How to schedule a load balancer to start/stop at specific times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, amazon-elb

I have a loadbalancer which as per my application requirement should be turned on at specific time (Ex. 9:00AM) and turned off at another specific time(Ex. 5:00PM). Is there any way to achieve this using any of the AWS services like CloudWatch, AutoScaling etc.,

Comment: You can't do this. You can only delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html) for any scheduled operation

In case your needs are not fulfilled by the built-in targets, you'll have to code your custom logic in an [AWS Lambda Function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)

Comment: I'd add, that you can't "turn off" a load balancer in AWS, you can delete it at 5 pm and create a new one at 9 am.

Comment: Deleting it would be a hefty task, is there any other way around?

Comment: You could remove the listener. Both the load balancer and the underlaying services would be up & running but disconnected